# las2las - Reproject (shift) from shifted X,Y projection to original projection

Tags: lidar, las, lastools

I have a .las projected in a shifted EPSG:2100 projection. Coordinates are shifted by X,Y as following:

- X: 58xxxx -> xxxx
- Y: 414yyyy -> yyyy

For EPSG:2100, projection parameters are given here: http://epsg.io/2100

I know that I just have to change *false_easting* & *false_northing* paramers but how can I implement the projection using las2las CLI?

Answer (score 0):

On the right side click on "target projection" and define your easting and northing parameters.
[image]